Proving the closure of a set in $R^2$
I’m having trouble calculating the closure of this set,
$A = \left\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^n : 0 < y < x^2 \wedge 0 < x < 1 \right\}.$
My solution is as follows: let's define another set
$
B = \left\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^n : 0 \leq y \leq x^2 \wedge 0 \leq x \leq 1 \right\}.
$
Then, I claim that $\overline{A} = B $. To prove this equality, I proceed with the first inclusion:
$
(x, y) \in \overline{A} \Rightarrow \exists (x_n, y_n) \in A \text{ such that } x_n \rightarrow x \wedge y_n \rightarrow y,$
$
\Rightarrow 0 < y_n < x_n^2 \wedge 0 < x_n < 1,
$
taking the limit
$
\Rightarrow 0 \leq y \leq x^2 \wedge 0 \leq x \leq 1,
$
$
\Rightarrow (x, y) \in B.
$
Then, for the other inclusion (where I’m getting stuck), I proceed as follows:
$
(x, y) \in B \Rightarrow 0 \leq y \leq x^2 \wedge 0 \leq x \leq 1.
$
Here, I try to form a sequence that tends to $(x, y)$ and belongs to $A$.
For example, let
$
x_n = \left(1 - \frac{2}{n}\right)x + \frac{1}{n}.
$
We see that $x_n \rightarrow x \wedge 0 < x_n < 1$,
but I can’t manage to find $y_n$ :'(

$y_n=(1-\frac 2 n)^{2}y$ will do for $y \ne 0$.
